# How to extract the variables out from “add_shortcode” function?

Tags: functions, shortcode, templates

In Wordpress, lets say i have a custom Shortcode function, like:

```
function foobar_func( $atts ){
    //whatever required processings here...
    $foo = "the value is foo!";
    $bar = "the value is bar!";
}
add_shortcode( 'myshortcode', 'foobar_func' );
//now .. echo the value of $foo here? <----------
```

As you can see, how can i get the processed value of a variable out from the function please? (as in the last line)

OR

How to pass the variable from this Function to the outside, please?

Comment: I think you're doing something wrong here, you want to echo the value directly in your `functions.php` file, before you render the theme?

Comment: Its not even in the `functions.php`, but just in the Template File. Whatever, i just need to do processing with the `Shortcode` (in the backend) instead of even printing the things out to Display. (In short, i need to get the value of a variable inside the `function`, from the outside of it.)

Comment: Wrap it in a class and use `$this->foo` to access it within the class or through a getter to access it externally.

Comment: hi @birgire can you give/code it as an answer please? Cos i still do not get what to do :(

Comment: But can you use the callback function directly? Why do you need a shortcode if you're not using it? Can you perhaps explain it a little bit more what you are trying to achieve - the big picture?

Comment: I'm trying to pass an ID from the custom shortcode (defined in the Page). Then parse that ID from the shortcode's Function. (Then I get a `ID variable` at this point) After that i need to run another/main function in the Template file, by passing the `ID variable` into that. ---- It is similar like, when i pass the `[myshortcode userid="1234"]` then the Template file will be generating the `User Details` by using another Function there. (But i need to parse the Shortcode, first, to know the ID. Then feed into my main Function)

Comment: Whatever, i need to pass a Variable from `Shortcode` to `Function` (process it), and then .. pass it to `a custom function` inside `Template` file. But here, it is stuck at the Shortcode's Function first.

Comment: Hi please kindly follow here. This is more descriptive. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059143/how-to-extract-the-variables-out-from-add-shortcode-function-in-wordpress

Comment: Why not run the `User Details` function from *within* the shortcode? ie, get the `ID` from the shortcode, do the `User Details` stuff, then output it, all as part of the shortcode?

Comment: @PatJ that is just an example. There's nothing doing with WP native functions actually. All are custom development works.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ays to do the trick, one possible is use a function that use a static variable.

However, before you can be able to get the arguments set in shortcode, the shortcode must be processed...

```
function foobar_func( $atts = array(), $out = FALSE ){
   static $args = array(
     'foo' => 'default foo',
     'bar' => 'default bar'
   );
   if ( $out ) return $args;
   $args = shortcode_atts( $args, $atts, 'myshortcode' );
   echo 'The value for "foo" argument set in shortcode is: ' . $args['foo'] . '<br>';
   echo 'and the value for "bar" argument set in shortcode is: ' . $args['bar'];
}
add_shortcode( 'myshortcode', 'foobar_func' );
```

And **after** the shortcode is processed, you can get all the arguments calling again the function with second arguments set to true:

```
$shortcode_args = foobar_func( NULL, TRUE );
```

If called **before** the shortcode is processed it always return default values.

Another way, probably more reliable, is to trigger a custom action, and use it to pass the shortcode arguments:

```
function foobar_func( $atts = array() ){
   $defaults = array(
     'foo' => 'default foo',
     'bar' => 'default bar'
   );
   $args = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $atts, 'myshortcode' );
   echo 'The value for "foo" argument set in shortcode is: ' . $args['foo'] . '<br>';
   echo 'and the value for "bar" argument set in shortcode is: ' . $args['bar'];
   // custom action
   do_action( 'myshortcode_processed', $args );
}
add_shortcode( 'myshortcode', 'foobar_func' );
```

and then hook the action to get arguments and use them:

```
add_action( 'myshortcode_processed', function( $shortcode_args ) {
  // do whatever you want with $shortcode_args
  var_dump( $shortcode_args );
});
```

Comment: Solution #1 is (potentially) Doing It Wrong. From the [`add_shortcode()` Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode): "Note that the function called by the shortcode should *never* produce output of any kind. Shortcode functions should *return* the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode. Producing the output directly will lead to unexpected results."